# Cross tabulation of co-occuring pairs of variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that has columns representing some variables. Each row corresponds to an instance. The presence of a particular variable at a given instance is indicated by a 1, its absence, by a 0.

```
# Construct dataframe.
df <- structure(list(var.1 = c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0), 
                     var.2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), 
                     var.3 = c(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1), 
                     var.4 = c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))

> df
#   var.1 var.2 var.3 var.4
# 1     0     1     1     0
# 2     1     1     1     0
# 3     0     0     0     0
# 4     0     0     1     1
# 5     0     1     0     1
# 6     1     0     0     1
# 7     0     0     1     1
```

I would like to know how to, preferably using `dplyr`, create a matrix that counts the frequency of co-occurrence between all pairs of variables. The result should look something like this:

```
> result.df
#       var.1 var.2 var.3 var.4
# var.1    NA     1     0     0
# var.2     1    NA     2     1
# var.3     0     2    NA     2
# var.4     1     1     2    NA
```

Thank you.

Comment: Between *var.2* and *var.3*, the count should be 2  also right?

Comment: Yes you are correct, sorry!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the columns are binary 1 or 0, you can also do this by multiplyting the columns together, which will result in 1 only if both columns are equal to 1, then summing

```
out <- sapply(df, function(x) colSums(df*x))
diag(out) <- NA
out
#       var.1 var.2 var.3 var.4
# var.1    NA     1     1     1
# var.2     1    NA     2     1
# var.3     1     2    NA     2
# var.4     1     1     2    NA
```

or using matrix multiplication

```
out <- t(df) %*% as.matrix(df)
diag(out) <- NA
out

#       var.1 var.2 var.3 var.4
# var.1    NA     1     1     1
# var.2     1    NA     2     1
# var.3     1     2    NA     2
# var.4     1     1     2    NA
```

Comment: The matrix multiplication is the most elegant solution, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

`df` is a matrix. In base R, we can use `outer` and count number of co-occurences of 1's for every 2 columns.

```
count_1s <- function(x, y) sum(df[, x] == 1 & df[, y] == 1)

mat <- outer(seq_len(ncol(df)), seq_len(ncol(df)), Vectorize(count_1s))
diag(mat) <- NA
dimnames(mat) <- list(colnames(df), colnames(df))

#        var.1 var.2 var.3 var.4
#var.1      NA     1     1     1
#var.2       1    NA     2     1
#var.3       1     2    NA     2
#var.4       1     1     2    NA
```

Comment: Nice solution! Is it possible to vectorize any function by using `Vectorize()` ?

Comment: @maydin don't go by it's name. `Vectorize` is just a wrapper over `mapply` :P

Comment: Ah sorry I meant to make it a data frame. My mistake!